# How to refer a field name in data frame if we don't have schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can we refer a particular field in dataframe if we don't have schema.
Can we refer some thing like col1,col2,col3,.....,etc instead of name.

I have a csv file like below.

```
arun|1001|hyd|x|y|z
suresh|1002|hyd|a|h|t
arun|1003|chn|e|g|e
suresh|1004|ban|r|f|w
```

How can i refer to first field and filter the records based on names to write it to a separate file.

All `arun` record and `suresh` I want to write to separate file like below.

```
arun|1001|hyd|x|y|z
arun|1003|chn|e|g|e
```

and

```
suresh|1002|hyd|a|h|t
suresh|1004|ban|r|f|w
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@getAs[T](i:Int):T

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Use default column name, c1, c2, etc
2. Use getAs() method from Row, i.e. in filter or mapper
3. Programatically specify schema

In Scala schema is generated as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(
    StructField("name", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("intValue", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dfFromLoad.rdd, schema)
```